# Asignar un formato a números

Tags: javascript

Tengo un formulario simple donde un campo input se ingresa un monto en dinero, que se multiplica por 365 para entregar un resultado en otro input que muestra la variable del resultado, el input del resultado tiene formato de miles solo si doy click en él. Es posible que esté formateado automáticamente.

¿Es posible que vaya formateando automáticamente? soy novato en este lenguaje y quisiera de su ayuda, espero me puedan orientar. Cabe destacar que los códigos o gran parte de ellos fueron rescatados de este misma web en otras preguntas.

Gracias.

**Código de Ejemplo**

```html
<script>
 function cuadro1() {
  var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value; 
  var myBox2 = 365
  var result = document.getElementById('result'); 
  var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;
  result.value = myResult;
 }
</script><!-- JS BOX1 -->


<script>
 function cuadro2() {
  var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box11').value; 
  var desayuno = 5000
  var semanas = 50
  var result2 = document.getElementById('result2'); 
  var myResult2 = myBox1 * desayuno * semanas;
  result2.value = myResult2;
 }
</script><!-- JS BOX2 -->

<script>
 function cuadro3() {
  var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box12').value; 
  var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box22').value;
  var meses = 12;
  var result3 = document.getElementById('result3'); 
  var myResult3 = (myBox1 * myBox2 * meses) * 1000;
  result3.value = myResult3;
 }
</script> <!-- JS BOX3 -->

<script>
 function format(input) {
  var num = input.value.replace(/\./g,'');
  if(!isNaN(num)){
   num = num.toString().split('').reverse().join('').replace(/(?=\d*\.?)(\d{3})/g,'$1.');
   num = num.split('').reverse().join('').replace(/^[\.]/,'');
   input.value = num;
  }

  else{ alert('Solo se permiten numeros');
  input.value = input.value.replace(/[^\d\.]*/g,'');
 }
}
</script> <!-- formato miles  input se ejecuta el formato al evento click, tecleo o cambio en input -->

<style>
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    /* display: none; <- Se bloquea Chrome al pasar el mouse por encima */
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0; /* <-- Aparentemente, todavía hay un margen, aunque esté oculto. */
}
input[type=number] {
    -moz-appearance:textfield; /* Firefox */
}
</style>

<form action="">
 <div class="box1">
  <h2> Cuadro 1 </h2>
  Si ahorras: $<input id="box1" type="text" oninput="cuadro1();format(this)" /> pesos todos los días.
  <br>
  <span>En un año ahorras: </span><input id="result" oninput="format(this)" onkeyup="format(this)" onchange="format(this)" type="text" id="result" />
 </div>
</form><!-- Fin Cuadro 1 -->

<div class="box2">
 <h2> Cuadro 2 </h2>
 Si llevas desayuno/almuerzo <input id="box11" type="text" oninput="cuadro2()"  oninput="format(this)" onkeyup="format(this)" onchange="format(this)"/> a la semana.
 <br>
 <span>En un año ahorras: </span><input type="text" id="result2" oninput="format(this)" onkeyup="format(this)" onchange="format(this)" />
</div><!-- Fin Cuadro 2 -->

<div class="box3">
 <h2> Cuadro 3 </h2>
 Si vas a la farmacia al mes <input id="box12" type="text" oninput="cuadro3()"  oninput="format(this)" onkeyup="format(this)" onchange="format(this)"/> veces y gastas $<input id="box22" type="text" oninput="cuadro3()"  oninput="format(this)" onkeyup="format(this)" onchange="format(this)"/>.
 <br>
 <span>En un año ahorras: </span><input oninput="format(this)" onkeyup="format(this)" onchange="format(this)" type="text" id="result3"   /> aproximadamente.
</div><!-- Fin Cuadro 3 -->
```

Answer (score 2):

Si entendí bien lo que puedes hacer es guardar la variable como número por un lado y usar `toLocaleString("de-DE")` por otro, `es-ES` no respeta el primer punto de miles:

```js
const input1 = document.getElementById("input1");
const input2 = document.getElementById("input2");

input1.addEventListener("input", (e) => {

  let valorNumerico = (+e.target.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, "").replace(/\./g, "") || "");

  input1.value = (valorNumerico).toLocaleString("de-DE");

  input2.value = (valorNumerico * 2).toLocaleString("de-DE");

});
```

```html
<input id="input1" type="text" placeholder="escribir numero" />
<input id="input2" type="text" />
```